# How to use angular with cloud firebase function in localhost

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

I have problem with using Angular with firebase functions in localhost. All I want is  if user delete his account, then firebase function should react something (like delete all stuff of deleted user in firestore db). For example:

Angular:

```
public deleteAccount(): Promise<void> {
    return this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.delete().then(() => {

      const test = this.angularFireFunctions.httpsCallable('httpFunction');
      test(null).subscribe((response) => {
        debugger;
      }, (error) => {
        debugger;
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.uiService.showSnackBar(error.message, 'error-snackbar');
    });
  }
```

Function:

```
export const httpFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => { // need cors, because of error in console
    return functions.auth.user().onDelete((user: admin.auth.UserRecord) => {
      return res.status(200).send(user.uid);
    });
  });
});
```

But even if I use code like this only for testing, after deleting the user, there is a request to httpFunction and it's ok, but the status is 'pending' all the time.

Second thing, in firestore console (in logs for function section) there is info like:

"Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions"

"Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'"

This account is free and I think this message is only an alert, but anyway, do you have any idea how can I use onDelete properly in Cloud firestore function?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you read through the Firebase Documentation on background functions / triggers. `onUserDeleted` is a trigger.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers

**** Here's the TL;DR: ****

You don't need to trigger background functions manually via an https call because they are fired automatically in response to events. Background functions work by exporting them from the entry-point (index.(ts|js)).

So, simply export your function from index.(ts|js) and deploy it.

```
export const onUserDeleted = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user: admin.auth.UserRecord) => {
      // Delete user in Firestore
      // Don't forget to return a Promise!
    });
  });
});
```

`onUserDeleted` will be fired in response to deleting the user. In your case, calling `this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.delete()` in Angular.

You can test this by simply using `console.log` in the onUserDeleted callback and viewing it in the firebase console under functions -> logs.